# How can I require calling dispose method?

Tags: flutter, dart, static-analysis

I'm trying to require (or at least warn in the linter) that when I create an object I also define when it should be disposed, if necessary. An example of this is the warning for `Sink`: `Close instances of dart.core.Sink`, which appears in VS Code if you create a `Sink` without ever calling `.close()`. The issue is that I have classes that define multiple `Sink` objects, so I close all of them in a dispose method for the class, which solves the `dart.core.Sink` warning but doesn't solve the underlying issue, because this method might never be called.

**Is there any way to create a similar error/warning for my own classes?** I've looked at adding new rules to the linter, but this seems like a lot of work, and before I go that far, I was wondering if there's any `mixin` or similar that would give me this functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Your can use `mustCallSuper` attribute like this:

```
  import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

  @mustCallSuper
  void dispose() {
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: No, unfortunately this isn't what I'm looking for. This only required that a subclass that overrides the method calls the super method.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think it's not possible.